# iPad & iPhone don't display my site background

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, background

On iPad and iPhone my sites background doesn't display.
On everything else browser works fine (Safari, Chrome, IE and Mozilla)

My css code is:

```
background:url(../photos/shutterstock2.jpg);
background-size:2800px 1500px;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-color: #94C5EB;
```

Comment: i read somewhere that is resolution problem, but when i put it at 800x600 , din't work

Comment: Did you try to change both the `background-size` and the size of `shutterstock2.jpg` itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```css
html { 
    background: url(../photos/shutterstock2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #94C5EB;
}
```

We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.

**This should give you an awesome and progressive CSS3 way!**

Comment: My site's background looks better and thank u for that but in ipad , no background, can u please tell me where did u read the above code, i loved it. thanks for your response

Comment: Can you explain in details what CSS above does?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov yes i can do that!

Comment: If you update your answer with explanations, that would be great!